# Displaying tables based on multiple conditions in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have five values that come from a form; like state1, state2, state3, state4, and state5.
Each value can be either 'New' or 'Closed'.
A Report will be displayed based on these values.
So, I created 5 tables, one each to be displayed on the report.
If a value is 'New' then display the respective table else no need to display.
So, I created XSLT like the below (this is just a fragment from my code).

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"cdata-section-elements="script msxsl:script"></xsl:output>
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <head><title>Report</title></head>
      <body>
       <table class="row1">
        <tr>
         <td align="left" colspan="2">
         <img src="../images/Logos/logo.gif" height="80"></img>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
   <xsl:if test="(state1='New') and (state2='Closed') and (state3='Closed') and (state4='Closed') and (state5='Closed')">
    <table class="row2">
     <tr>
      <td class="section" uniqueID="ms__id17">
       <b>Details(S1)</b>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <!--some rows -->
    </table>
    </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="(state1='New') and (state2='New') and (state3='Closed') and   (state4='Closed') and (state5='Closed')">
    <table class="row2">
     <tr>
      <td class="section" uniqueID="ms__id18">
       <b>Details(S1)</b>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <!--some rows -->
    </table> 
    <table class="row3">
     <tr>
      <td class="section" uniqueID="ms__id19">
       <b>Details(S2)</b>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <!--some rows -->
    </table> 
   </xsl:if>
   <!--more conditions-->
         </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I keep on giving conditions like this I should give 5! conditions.

Is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: What's your xml look like?

Comment: Yes. The problem here is that your variables are "unrelated" (that is, there's no way to do some batch processing on all slateN variable). Maybe if we have a look at your XML we can find a way to process all the slateN values automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want (use or instead of and)?

```
<xsl:if test="(state1='New') or (state2='New') or (state3='New') or (state4='New') or (state5='New')">
<table class="row2">
 <tr>
  <td class="section" uniqueID="ms__id17">
   <b>Details(S1)</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <!--some rows -->
</table>
</xsl:if>
```